# Flutter Desktop-How can I add c++ packages to my project

Tags: c++, flutter, windows, flutter-windows

I was trying to print pdf file using flutter in desktop but unfortunately most flutter packages not worked, so I am trying to make that task in native code(c++) and make channel between it and Flutter.
On of the most famous package in c++ for printing is Aspose.PDF .Therefore, is there anyway to add this package to my project.

I tried to add the package from visual studio ,but I don't have enough knowledge to do it.